# Formatting a conditional table of coefficients in LaTeX

Tags: tables, math-mode, formatting

I'm totally blanking on how to format this, or even what to use as a search term to see if anyone has asked about it before. I would like to make a conditional table of coefficients (ie. two tables with use dependant on another variable in the equation), here is an example that I pulled out of another paper:

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, I edited your question to inline the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this will get you started

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{array}{@{}l}
a_{11}={+}0.456\times10^{-1}\\
a_{12}={-}0.987\times10^{-2}\\
a_{13}={-}0.1237\times10^{-10}
\end{array}
\right\}
\text{ for $0\leq X \leq 200$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```